# xamarin get textview value to store in database

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using the background location services to get user current location , I want to get the textview value to store in database, how to get value from textview

```
 latText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lat);
        userName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.userName);

        longText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.longx);
        altText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.alt);
        speedText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.speed);
        bearText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.bear);
        accText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.acc);

        altText.Text = "altitude.";
        longText.Text = "longitude";
        speedText.Text = "speed";
        bearText.Text = "bearing";
        accText.Text = "accuracy";
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the textview value to store in database, how to get value from textview

Use the following codes to get the value from `TextView`:

```
var text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lat).Text;
```